# How do I install wkhtmltophp on Laravel 4 running on Windows 8?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I have a WAMP server on Win 8 running Laravel 4 and I'm trying to get wkhtmltophp to work properly.

I ran the Windows installation program I downloaded from [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) (the 64-bit "Windows (MSVC 2013)").

I'd first installed it into C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf, then I tried installing it into the laravel /vendor directory under C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\gitt\vendor\wkhtmltopdf

naturally I changed my folder to match under /app/config/local/laravel-pdf.php and in this file I have

```
return array(
    //'bin' => '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
    'bin' => base_path() . '/vendor/wkhtmltopdf/bin'
);
```

And every time I run the script, I get the error "proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 5"

Not sure what I'm missing. Another developer, on a Mac, was able to install it on his side, so laravel also has the /vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf installed, so I changed line 92 to:

```
class WkHtmlToPdf
{
    #protected $bin = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
    protected $bin = '/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs/gitt/vendor/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe';
etc......
```

Still got the same error. I'm lost! Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

[image: error screenshot]